# add nth-child class dynamicaly

Tags: jquery, html

Need to add class dynamically (by jQuery)

```
<ul>
    <li class="green">Green</li>
    <li class="red">red</li>
    <li class="black">black</li>

    <li class="">Green</li>
    <li class="">red</li>
    <li class="">black</li>

    <li class="">Green</li>
    <li class="">red</li>
    <li class="">black</li>

</ul>
```

my code

```
jQuery('ul').each(function(){
                jQuery(this).find('li:nth-child(1n)').addClass('green');
                jQuery(this).find('li:nth-child(2n)').addClass('red');
                jQuery(this).find('li:nth-child(3n)').addClass('black');
  });
```

I have added static class on first row(means first 3 li),  Need more rows same as first row
You can Use jQuery 
 Demo here 
http://jsfiddle.net/WfKeY/

Comment: Mind explaining why wouldn't you add them by hand?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I have tried, i ll add my code

Comment: Updated http://jsfiddle.net/zaMUU/1/, see the problem, Please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be repeating the classes every 3 elements, so use `3n`, `3n+/-1`, `3n+/-2` :

```
jQuery('ul').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).find('li:nth-child(3n-2)').addClass('green');
    jQuery(this).find('li:nth-child(3n-1)').addClass('red');
    jQuery(this).find('li:nth-child(3n)').addClass('black');
});​
```

Updated demo : http://jsfiddle.net/WfKeY/2/

Comment: Interesting Thank you so much ..., Great job

Answer (score 1):

Now that I understand the question, here is an alternative:

```
var $li = $('ul > li');
$li.each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass($li.eq(i%3).attr('class'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zaMUU/5/

Comment: You mean you want the class name to be equal to the text?

Comment: Sorry still miss-understood. I think gion_13 has the answer you are looking for.

Comment: You dont understand my question , (English is not my first language , problem is my language i think), Thanks for help

Comment: nothing wrong with your question. some people give down votes without good reason.